# Optimize Scipy Sparse Matrix Factorization code for SGD

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I'm working on implementing the stochastic gradient descent algorithm for recommender systems (see Funk) using sparse matrices with Scipy.

This is how a first basic implementation looks like:

```
N = self.model.shape[0] #no of users
M = self.model.shape[1] #no of items
self.p = np.random.rand(N, K)
self.q = np.random.rand(M, K)
rows,cols = self.model.nonzero()        
for step in xrange(steps):
    for u, i in zip(rows,cols):
        e=self.model-np.dot(self.p,self.q.T) #calculate error for gradient
        p_temp = learning_rate * ( e[u,i] * self.q[i,:] - regularization * self.p[u,:])
        self.q[i,:]+= learning_rate * ( e[u,i] * self.p[u,:] - regularization * self.q[i,:])
        self.p[u,:] += p_temp
```

I have two questions and I am hoping some seasoned python coders / recommender systems experts here could provide me with some insight into this:

1) How often should the error e be adjusted? It is not clear from Funk's and Koren's papers if it should be once for every rating or if it should be once per every factor. Meaning, should i take it out of the for loop, leave it there, or put it even deeper (over the k iterations) ?

2) Unfortunately, my code is pretty slow, taking about 20 minutes on ONE iteration over a 100k ratings dataset. This means that computing the factorization over the whole dataset takes about 10 hours. I was thinking that this is probably due to the sparse matrix for loop. I've tried expressing the q and p changes using fancy indexing but since I'm still pretty new at scipy and numpy, I couldn't figure a better way to do it. Do you have any pointers on how i could avoid iterating over the rows and columns of the sparse matrix explicitly?

Comment: Which matrix is the scipy sparse matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be other optimizations available, but this one alone should go a long way...

When you do `e = self.model - np.dot(self.p,self.q.T)`, the resulting `e` is a dense matrix the same size as your `model`. You later only use `e[u, i]` in your loop, so you are throwing away what probably are millions of computed values. If you simply replace that line with:

```
e = self.model[u, i] - np.dot(self.p[u, :], self.q[i, :])
```

and then replace `e[u, i]` with `e`, you will spare yourself a huge amount both of computations and memory accesses, which should boost performance by a lot.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great improvement. I also did some other improvements. I transposed q from the very beginning and called the column directly, instead of calling and transposing the row. I also integrated the learning rate into the error , because it was being called three times. All in all, I manage to get one step to take only about 10 seconds now! Do you think it's worth optimising further with Cython?

Comment: Yes, it almost cetainly is... The problem is that you are updating your `p` and `q` vectors as you progress over the non-zero entries of `model`. This makes it very hard to get rid of the for loops, because `p` and `q` are different for every entry of `model`. If you could delay updating of `p` and `q` until the full `model` has been processed, then you would get different results, but you could speed things up a lot without Cython or C. With your algorithm, I cannot think of any way around that...

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Time to learn myself some Cython then! I'll be tackling the Netflix dataset soon, so I need all the speed I can get. I'm going to mark this as answered then.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the recommendation that Jaime offered, it would be very easy to get performance improvements by using Numba.

There is a tutorial on Numba and matrix factorization [here](http://www.fico.com/en/blogs/analytics-optimization/a-moment-of-science-llvm-example/).  When Numba works, it requires much less effort than rewriting your code in Cython.  In a nutshell, you need to import numba:

```
from numba.decorators import jit
```

And then add a decorator to your matrix factorization function, by simply adding this:

```
@jit
```

Before the method definition.